# I have a url in the format www.abc.com/mypage#yourId=ASDF2345. How to read the value of yourid using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, querystringparameter

In my application i have a url in the format

`www.abc.com/mypage#yourId=ASDF2345`.

How can i read back the value of yourId parameter from the Request object in asp.net , c# ?

If it would have been

`www.abc.com/mypage?yourId=ASDF2345`,

then i would have got this from the QueryString collection in the Request object. But there is a `#` before the yourId parameter and its not being provided by the QueryString collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash you are referring to does not actually get sent to the server by the browser. It's client-side only, C# can't "see" it.

If you must have that value, you can get it with the document.location.hash property in Javascript and send it back to the server via AJAX.

This is made easier by [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) or [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/blog/jquery/2010/05/05/jquery-address-12-ajax-crawling-url-building-and-more.html), which detect changes in the hash location, and can trigger events.

Answer (score 2):

The part of the url that follows the `#` is called the "fragment identifier", and there is no way to access this information on the server.  In fact, it's never even sent to the server -- the specification reserves the fragment identifier for the purpose of identifying a *fragment* of the document that is located by the rest of the url. The spec actually requires that the browser strip the fragment id from the url before sending the url in the HTTP request.

You can access the fragment id in the browser via javascript.  The property is called `document.location.hash`.

Answer (score 1):

Read it on the client side using jQuery and transfer manually to server.

**Example:**

```
var url = "www.abc.com/mypage#yourId=ASDF2345";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')); // '#yourId=ASDF2345'
```

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/hFNns/)

**And remember that the user can change the hash as he/she wants. Check the hash before using it.**